# Kotlin - How can I use a recyclerView in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I started using fragments and I'm still trying to learn how to use them properly. On the project I'm doing I want to use a recyclerView that shows a list of items that are stored in a database. I'm having some trouble doing it though as my recyclerView doesn't show any of the items.

The fragment where I want to show the recyclerView is like this:

```
package com.example.is4gestaointegrada.fragments

import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.is4gestaointegrada.Adapter.ArtigoAdapter
import com.example.is4gestaointegrada.DBHandlers.DBHandler
import com.example.is4gestaointegrada.MainActivity.Companion.dbHandler
import com.example.is4gestaointegrada.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_ver_artigos.view.*

private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"


class VerArtigos : Fragment() {
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private var listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            listener = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
        }
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

        dbHandler = DBHandler(context!!, null, null, 1)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ver_artigos, container, false)

        viewArtigos(view)

        return view
    }


    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        listener = null
    }

    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri)
    }

    private fun viewArtigos(view : View){
        val artigosList = dbHandler.getArtigos(context!!)
        val adapter = ArtigoAdapter(context!!, artigosList)
        val rv : RecyclerView = view.rv_artigos
        rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        rv.adapter = adapter
    }


    companion object {
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            VerArtigos().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The Handler's function code is this:

```
    fun getArtigos(mCtx : Context) : ArrayList<Artigo>{
        val qry = "SELECT * FROM $DB_ARTIGO_TABLE"
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(qry, null)
        val artigos = ArrayList<Artigo>()

        if (cursor.count == 0){
            Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Não foram encontrados artigos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                val artigo = Artigo()
                artigo.artigoNome = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_ARTIGO_NOME))
                artigo.artigoAbreviada = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_ARTIGO_ABREVIADA))
                artigo.artigoExtensa = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_ARTIGO_EXTENSA))
                artigo.artigoFamiliaCodigo = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_ARTIGO_FAMILIACODIGO))
                artigo.artigoFamiliaDescricao = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_ARTIGO_FAMILIADESCRICAO))
                artigo.artigoCodigoIVA = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_ARTIGO_CODIGOIVA))
                artigo.artigoPreco = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_ARTIGO_PRECO))
            }
        }

        cursor.close()
        db.close()
        return artigos
    }
```

The Adapter is like this:

```
package com.example.is4gestaointegrada.Adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.is4gestaointegrada.DBModels.Artigo
import com.example.is4gestaointegrada.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.lo_artigos.view.*

class ArtigoAdapter (mCtx : Context, val artigos : ArrayList<Artigo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArtigoAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    val mCtx = mCtx

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val txtArtigoNome = itemView.txt_NomeArtigo
        val txtArtigoDesc = itemView.txt_ArtigoDesc
        val txtArtigoPreco = itemView.txt_ArtigoPreco
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ArtigoAdapter.ViewHolder {
       val v = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.lo_artigos, p0, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return artigos.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ArtigoAdapter.ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        val artigo : Artigo = artigos[p1]
        p0.txtArtigoNome.text = artigo.artigoNome
        p0.txtArtigoDesc.text = artigo.artigoAbreviada
        p0.txtArtigoDesc.text = artigo.artigoPreco.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getArtigos` function never adds anything to `artigos`, so you always return an empty `ArrayList`.

You need to add it to the list in your `while (cursor.moveToNext()){` loop.